# Differential Geometry books

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

For quite a while I have been interested in differential geometry. In 1-2 months I might find myself with some time on my hands. I have heard and cursorily flipped through a few of them but I would really appreciate a more informed opinion. If anyone would comment about the style, prerequisites, etc of these books I would be grateful.

1. Semi-Riemannian Geometry with applications to Relativity (Barret O'Neill)
2. Elementary Differential Geometry (Barret O'Neill)
3. The Geometry of Physics (Theodore Frankel)
4. Differential Geometric Structures (Walter Poor)
5. A Comprehensive Course of Differential Geometry (Spivak) (Vol 1 & 2 Maybe?)
6. Tensor analysis on Manifolds (Bishop & Goldberg)
7. Differential Forms & Connections (RWR Darling)

I like what I have seen of 1,2 & 3.

1 seems to be the coolest book of the lot. 2 seems to be the standard barring do carmo. 3 covers a LOT but it isn't all that rigorous.

**Do I need to read 2 before I read 1? Because 1 seems to be pretty wild stuff like singularity theorems and since they're both written by the same author so is 2 a prerequisite for 1 or I can jump in directly?**

For some background, I have read Hubbard's Vector calculus book and Linear algebra done right by axler and linear algebra by strang. I have also worked through the first few chapters of apostol's mathematical analysis book so I am not new to rigor.

Comment: If you do not know anything about differential geometry I recommend that you start with a book like Elementary Differential Geometry from Christian Bär. It's fun to read and gives you an intuition about the basic concepts. After that I recommend Introduction to Smooth Manifolds from John Lee. Learning Differential Geometry and later Riemannian Geometry or Symplectic Geometry is like learning a language and if you start with advanced topics you might get lost.

Comment: As you are already familiar with real analysis, I would recommend you Differential geometry of curves and surfaces from Manfredo do Carmo. I used it in my first course of differential geometry and I can say it is good book to start. The proofs are well explained and the author make sure to present several examples. Some challenging exercises too.

Comment: @Cornman I'd like to very much but right now I am trying to sink my teeth into baby rudin

Comment: @nmasanta I had read through this post and several others before posting this .  I guess my main question is whether I can directly start reading 1 before I read 2. It seems by far the coolest book in the lot. Also personalized comments by someone who went through these texts on their own would help

Comment: Another book to be aware of is Tristan Needham's new book [Visual Differential Geometry and Forms: A Mathematical Drama in Five Acts](https://www.amazon.com/Visual-Differential-Geometry-Forms-Mathematical/dp/0691203695). Needham's previous book Visual Complex Analysis is very popular.